# Laravel Pagination issue

Tags: laravel

this is my code

```
$posts = Post::all()->paginate(3);
return view('home', compact('posts'));
```

and the error message is **Bad Method Call**

Answer (score 3):

**all() return a Collection instance, not a Builder instance.**

If you want to call paginate() non-statically

```
Post::query()->paginate(3);
```

statically

```
Post::paginate(3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$posts = Post::paginate(3); 
return view('home', compact('posts'));
```